# Wallis' Formula

Tags: contour-integration

How can I show the following, for $n\geq 0$:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_{\ \Gamma} \frac{1}{z} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n} dz
$$

using a contour $\Gamma$ defined as the unit circle centered at the origin and oriented counterclocwkise.

Ref. Complex Analysis by M.W. Wong

Comment: You're missing an $i$ in the denominator of the factor before the first integral. Do you already know the residue theorem?

Comment: ... so I should be doing a Laurent series expansion to get the residues at the poles and if my memory is good, the integral is equal to the sum of the residues?

Comment: Yes (if you fix the missing $i$). If you look at the integrand a little more closely, you will see that the poles are few in number, and the residue easily computed.

Comment: Wong's book explicitely states $2\pi$... perhaps its is to cancel out with the $2\pi i$ of the residue formula...

Comment: The _first_ integral. That ought to be $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{1}{z}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n}\,dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

The residue theorem asks for the $z^{-1}$ term of $z^{-1}(z+z^{-1})^{2n}$, which is the same as the constant coefficient of $(z+z^{-1})^{\color{Red}{2n}}$. If I said we get $\binom{\color{Red}{2n}}{n}$ would you know how the binomial appears?

Comment: Seems like the binomial expansion formula in disguise...